# Classified Enron Email Dataset

Tags: machine-learning, classification, dataset, databases

I'm building a system able to classify emails into different categories (positive, negative, out of office, etc...) and I'm looking for a dataset of already classified emails to avoid hand classification on a 70k database.

I know it exists the Enron email dataset but do you know if it exists a version of this dataset with classified emails ? Or any other already classified email dataset ?

Comment: I assume this is a question for the Open Data SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the corpus from this [site](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./enron/). To the best of my knowledge this is the most complete email corpus available. A project to label a subset of this email corpus can be found on this [UC Berkley site](http://bailando.sims.berkeley.edu/enron_email.html). I am not sure though whether these emails have the right training labels for you.

Comment: Even if categories aren't exactly what I'm looking for It's a really good working basis! I'll just wait one or two days before accepting your answer in case a better choice is given to me.

Answer (score 0):

[The Enron Corpus:
A New Dataset for Email Classification Research](http://nl.ijs.si/janes/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/klimtyang04b.pdf) paper describes the kind of data set you want.

The paper mentions the following link to download the data set:

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./enron/

Additionally, the paper also mentions various other papers which have used smaller data sets related to email classification which may not be of much use given this larger dataset.

Comment: No. This paper is about the number of mail per user, the number of message per thread and the number of folder per user but not about mail content classification.

Comment: @JérémyPouyet The paper does mention the task of classifying emails into folders. Please go through section 2 on page 3.

Comment: @JérémyPouyet I have added the link to the dataset from the paper.